# How to configure build.gradle in multi project (spring boot) to work properly in herok?

Tags: spring-boot, heroku

When I was deployoing on herok. The stage task started. It created todo-api-all.jar but it's badly built because it won't start and profiles don't work. How to configure it correctly

Task stage createm

Project structure:
[image]

root build.gradle :

```
plugins {
    id 'idea'
    id "com.github.johnrengelman.shadow" version "7.1.2"
}

ext {
    log4jVersion = '2.9.1'
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral() // maven { url: 'http://jcenter.bintray.com' }
    }
}


apply from: file('gradle/heroku/clean.gradle')

subprojects {
    apply plugin: 'com.github.johnrengelman.shadow'
    apply plugin: 'java'

    group = "be.ordina.jworks.${rootProject.name}"


    apply from: file("$rootProject.projectDir/gradle/heroku/stage.gradle")

}
```

subproject:

todo-api gradle.build:

```
 plugins {
    id "org.springframework.boot" version "2.6.4"
    id "io.spring.dependency-management" version "1.0.11.RELEASE"

}


jar {
    manifest {
        attributes(
                'Main-Class': 'be.ordina.jworks.todoapi.TodoApplication'
        )
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa')
    implementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
    implementation('com.h2database:h2:2.1.210')
    implementation 'org.postgresql:postgresql:42.3.3'
    implementation('javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:2.4.0-b180830.0359')
    testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:2.6.4')
    implementation(project(':todo-ui'))
}
```

todo-ui gradle.build:

```
plugins {
  id 'java'
  id "com.github.node-gradle.node" version "3.2.1"
}

node {
  version = '16.14.0'
  npmVersion = '8.3.1'
  download = true
}

jar.dependsOn 'npm_run_build'

jar {
  from 'dist/todo-ui' into 'static'
}
```

stage.gradle:

```
task stage(dependsOn: ['clean', 'shadowJar'])

task copyToLib(type: Copy) {
  from "$buildDir/libs"
  into "$rootProject.buildDir/libs"
}
copyToLib.dependsOn(shadowJar)
stage.dependsOn(copyToLib)
```

log:

```
2022-03-18T05:25:56.916210+00:00 app[web.1]: .   ____          _            __ _ _
2022-03-18T05:25:56.916221+00:00 app[web.1]: /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
2022-03-18T05:25:56.916240+00:00 app[web.1]: ( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
2022-03-18T05:25:56.916257+00:00 app[web.1]: \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
2022-03-18T05:25:56.916538+00:00 app[web.1]: '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
2022-03-18T05:25:56.916539+00:00 app[web.1]: =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
2022-03-18T05:25:56.918233+00:00 app[web.1]: :: Spring Boot ::
2022-03-18T05:25:56.918253+00:00 app[web.1]:
2022-03-18T05:25:56.999452+00:00 app[web.1]: 05:25:56.997 [main] INFO be.ordina.jworks.todoapi.TodoApplication - Starting TodoApplication using Java 17.0.2 o
n 5e72682a-8641-4d0c-8fb0-bae19747dcad with PID 4 (/app/build/libs/todo-api-all.jar started by u8516 in /app)
2022-03-18T05:25:57.000016+00:00 app[web.1]: 05:25:56.999 [main] DEBUG be.ordina.jworks.todoapi.TodoApplication - Running with Spring Boot, Spring
2022-03-18T05:25:57.002530+00:00 app[web.1]: 05:25:57.002 [main] INFO be.ordina.jworks.todoapi.TodoApplication - No active profile set, falling back to 1 def
ault profile: "default"
2022-03-18T05:25:57.003511+00:00 app[web.1]: 05:25:57.003 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication - Loading source class be.ordina.jworks.tod
oapi.TodoApplication
2022-03-18T05:25:57.067699+00:00 app[web.1]: 05:25:57.067 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicati
onContext - Refreshing org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@679b62af
2022-03-18T05:25:57.076432+00:00 app[web.1]: 05:25:57.076 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared
 instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor'
2022-03-18T05:25:57.129886+00:00 app[web.1]: 05:25:57.129 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner - Ignored becaus
e not a concrete top-level class: URL [jar:file:/app/build/libs/todo-api-all.jar!/be/ordina/jworks/todoapi/todo/TodoRepository.class]
2022-03-18T05:25:57.135001+00:00 app[web.1]: 05:25:57.134 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner - Identified can
didate component class: URL [jar:file:/app/build/libs/todo-api-all.jar!/be/ordina/jworks/todoapi/todo/TodoService.class]
2022-03-18T05:25:57.150821+00:00 app[web.1]: 05:25:57.150 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner - Identified can
didate component class: URL [jar:file:/app/build/libs/todo-api-all.jar!/be/ordina/jworks/todoapi/todo/TodoController.class]
2022-03-18T05:25:57.188206+00:00 app[web.1]: 05:25:57.187 [main] ERROR org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication - Application run failed
2022-03-18T05:25:57.188215+00:00 app[web.1]: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No auto configuration classes found in META-INF/spring.factories. If you are
 using a custom packaging, make sure that file is correct.
2022-03-18T05:25:57.188216+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.util.Assert.notEmpty(Assert.java:470)
```